# Azure Storage Blob and Queue Secured access to external Application

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a Storage account in our Azure "https://MysecuredStorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net" where we need to provide access to an external vendor to push the data to our blob. Since it is a PAAS service by default it is accessible with "Shared access Signature" .

However, as part of Security compliance policy in our ORG, i can not allow any service publicly accessible, so i have created a private end points to access Storage account internally.

Do we have any other Network Firewall Solution to allow blob access to external vendor application that too without whitelisting their Public IP in Storage account Network Firewall.
Any Firewall/NAT kind of solution that can be used to provide a secured connection externally.

Answer (score 0):

If it's being accessed manually or from a specific machine/user you can consider Azure [Point-to-Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) with a VPN Gateway else look into a [Site-to-site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-classic-portal) VPN setup with the vendors firewall.

It's not that hard to setup and will give them access directly to the subnet/IP of your choice. The setup complexity would depend on the firewall the vendor uses but in general its not too bad.

That's the easiest option I can think of.

Comment: I need to give access to my Storage account to an Application deployed in AWS instance like (SnowFlake) DB. My Storage has a Private link created as per our security standards we should not use  public DNS provided by MS.

Comment: Yes what I'm proposing has nothing to do with using the public DNS name of the storage account. I'm suggesting that you allow the vendor to connect to your network using the Azure P2S or S2S solutions - which is my version of the 'other network firewall solution' you mentioned. If public access isn't allowed, then the only other way is private access - the above are just ways of accessing privately.